# Need help in converting DirectoryServices code to PrincipalContext

Tags: c#-4.0, directoryservices, principalcontext

```
DirectorySearcher deSearch;SearchResultCollection result;
deSearch.SearchRoot = baseResult.GetDirectoryEntry();// I know this one can be done like - PrincipalContext pContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, deSearch.SearchRoot.Path);
deSearch.Filter = "(&(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))(name=" + name + "))"; //???? **Not sure how to apply the filter in Principal Context**
results = deSearch.FindAll();
```

Please help me in applying filter in principlecontext

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PrincipalSearcher` to search for a particular user.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{ 
   UserPrincipal searchUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   searchUser.GivenName = "Name";

   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(searchUser);
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
     //found will contain the info   
   } 
}
```

You can also use `UserPrincipal`.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, "DN"))
   if (user != null)
   {
      //user contains info
   }
}
```

You can define different `IdentityType` if you want to search by `samAccountName` or etc.